# OpenCL clGetPlatformIDs exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencl

I use the HelloWorld example from the samples that came with the installation of this package

[AMD PACKAGE](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/)

The problem is that I can't run any example because of an error.

```
    cl_uint numPlatforms;   //the NO. of platforms
    cl_platform_id platform = NULL; //the chosen platform
    cl_int  status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
```

The following block of code produces an error. Status is set to -858993460 at the end of this statement. An exception is thrown saying

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x7429C9F5 in AtomicCounters.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000."
```

I am using visual studio 2012, Windows 7 64-BIT and AMD GPU

I can't find enough resources to resolve the error. Please help me.

---

### The entire source code of HelloWorld.cpp

```
/**********************************************************************
Copyright ©2013 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

•   Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
•   Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or
 other materials provided with the distribution.

THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
 WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
 DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS
 OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
********************************************************************/

// For clarity,error checking has been omitted.

#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAILURE 1

using namespace std;

/* convert the kernel file into a string */
int convertToString(const char *filename, std::string& s)
{
    size_t size;
    char*  str;
    std::fstream f(filename, (std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary));

    if(f.is_open())
    {
        size_t fileSize;
        f.seekg(0, std::fstream::end);
        size = fileSize = (size_t)f.tellg();
        f.seekg(0, std::fstream::beg);
        str = new char[size+1];
        if(!str)
        {
            f.close();
            return 0;
        }

        f.read(str, fileSize);
        f.close();
        str[size] = '\0';
        s = str;
        delete[] str;
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"Error: failed to open file\n:"<<filename<<endl;
    return FAILURE;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    /*Step1: Getting platforms and choose an available one.*/
    cl_uint numPlatforms;   //the NO. of platforms
    cl_platform_id platform = NULL; //the chosen platform
    cl_int  status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
    if (status != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "Error: Getting platforms!" << endl;
        return FAILURE;
    }

    /*For clarity, choose the first available platform. */
    if(numPlatforms > 0)
    {
        cl_platform_id* platforms = (cl_platform_id* )malloc(numPlatforms* sizeof(cl_platform_id));
        status = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, platforms, NULL);
        platform = platforms[0];
        free(platforms);
    }

    /*Step 2:Query the platform and choose the first GPU device if has one.Otherwise use the CPU as device.*/
    cl_uint             numDevices = 0;
    cl_device_id        *devices;
    status = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &numDevices);    
    if (numDevices == 0)    //no GPU available.
    {
        cout << "No GPU device available." << endl;
        cout << "Choose CPU as default device." << endl;
        status = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 0, NULL, &numDevices);    
        devices = (cl_device_id*)malloc(numDevices * sizeof(cl_device_id));
        status = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, numDevices, devices, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        devices = (cl_device_id*)malloc(numDevices * sizeof(cl_device_id));
        status = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, numDevices, devices, NULL);
    }


    /*Step 3: Create context.*/
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL,1, devices,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    /*Step 4: Creating command queue associate with the context.*/
    cl_command_queue commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices[0], 0, NULL);

    /*Step 5: Create program object */
    const char *filename = "HelloWorld_Kernel.cl";
    string sourceStr;
    status = convertToString(filename, sourceStr);
    const char *source = sourceStr.c_str();
    size_t sourceSize[] = {strlen(source)};
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, &source, sourceSize, NULL);

    /*Step 6: Build program. */
    status=clBuildProgram(program, 1,devices,NULL,NULL,NULL);

    /*Step 7: Initial input,output for the host and create memory objects for the kernel*/
    const char* input = "GdkknVnqkc";
    size_t strlength = strlen(input);
    cout << "input string:" << endl;
    cout << input << endl;
    char *output = (char*) malloc(strlength + 1);

    cl_mem inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, (strlength + 1) * sizeof(char),(void *) input, NULL);
    cl_mem outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY , (strlength + 1) * sizeof(char), NULL, NULL);

    /*Step 8: Create kernel object */
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program,"helloworld", NULL);

    /*Step 9: Sets Kernel arguments.*/
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputBuffer);
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&outputBuffer);

    /*Step 10: Running the kernel.*/
    size_t global_work_size[1] = {strlength};
    status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    /*Step 11: Read the cout put back to host memory.*/
    status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, outputBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, strlength * sizeof(char), output, 0, NULL, NULL);

    output[strlength] = '\0';   //Add the terminal character to the end of output.
    cout << "\noutput string:" << endl;
    cout << output << endl;

    /*Step 12: Clean the resources.*/
    status = clReleaseKernel(kernel);               //Release kernel.
    status = clReleaseProgram(program);             //Release the program object.
    status = clReleaseMemObject(inputBuffer);       //Release mem object.
    status = clReleaseMemObject(outputBuffer);
    status = clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);   //Release  Command queue.
    status = clReleaseContext(context);             //Release context.

    if (output != NULL)
    {
        free(output);
        output = NULL;
    }

    if (devices != NULL)
    {
        free(devices);
        devices = NULL;
    }

    std::cout<<"Passed!\n";
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the CL runtime to me. Try using `clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, &numPlatforms)` - not suggesting that this will be the "right" thing to do, just this may stop it from crashing...

Comment: If it was me, I'd try to step into the function to see why it's going wrong - but then I've worked with similar functions in EGL/GLES and often had to debug them (because I worked within the graphics team for Symbian, so it was part of my job to figure out why these sort of things don't work).

Comment: @MatsPetersson It I am not experienced enough to do this. The error is in SDKApplication.cpp. I don't think I can fix it.

Comment: I think the problem may be a combination of two different things: 1) Your system has no runtime support for any gpu devices installed, and 2) the amd library you are using doesn't handle this situation properly. To confirm that opencl gpu runtime support is properly installed, check using an independent app such as http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/. This app does work on my system by the way.

Comment: @ScottD Amazing idea. I got this error after running it " GPU CAPS VIEWER: swiss made video card information utlity (OpenGL and OpenCL) has stopped working." I assume its my system that can't support a gpu. However by system do you mean operating system or hardware?

Comment: The gpu caps viewer is a well written utility. I have seen it recover from open cl calls that crash when my app calls them. But it looks like its recovery mechanism is not working in this case. Anyway, it sounds like you need to find the correct gpu driver download from the AMD website. Which model AMD gpu do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem under W7 32bit, nVIDIA and VS2010. (Same exact error in the same function with the same return code)

I dunno what is causing it, but **running the app as admin and with Windows XP compatibility enabled fixed the issue**.

I think is some kind of permissions on the operating system/driver. Or maybe something related on VS2010, and their relation to the DLLs??

Answer (score 1):

http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html

```
cl_int clGetPlatformIDs (cl_uint num_entries,
                     cl_platform_id *platforms, cl_uint *num_platforms)
clGetPlatformIDs (0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
```

The function "returns CL_INVALID_VALUE if num_entries is equal to zero and platforms is not NULL, or if both num_platforms and platforms are NULL", but does not check for platforms being NULL if num_platforms isn't, so it goes and tries to read 0x00000000, and gives you this error. It should work with `clGetPlatformIDs (1, &platform, &numPlatforms);`.

Answer (score 1):

Same error for me, under Windows Vista 64 bit, VS2008.

Also running clinfo from command prompt, it crashed.

I have solved simply updating the video driver.
I hope it can help :)